# Conditional to show logo A or logo B based on parent state

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a menu in which I would like to show a large logo if the toggle is 'open' and a small logo if the toggle is 'closed.' Having trouble with the concept of 'watching' the parent state from the child 'logo' component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Logo from './Logo'
import Nav from './Navbar'
import Meta from './Meta'
import HeaderStyle from './Header.css'

class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isToggleOn: false
    }

    // Bind function (updateState) to class (Header)
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this)
  }

  updateState() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <header>
        <Logo />
        <Nav />
        <Meta />
        <button onClick={this.updateState}>
          {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'CLOSE' : 'OPEN'}
        </button>
      </header>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import LogoImg from '../../img/logo.png'
import LogoMinImg from '../../img/logo-min.png'

class Logo extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="logo-wrap">
        <img src={this.state.isToggleOn ? LogoImg : LogoMinImg} className="logo" alt=""/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Logo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass that `isToggleOn` prop to the `Logo` component. If the parent re-renders, the child will re-render as well.

`<Logo isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn} />`

and then inside the `Logo`:

`<img src={this.props.isToggleOn ? LogoImg : LogoMinImg} className="logo" alt="" />`

Comment: Yea, I am still getting that to adhere somewhere in my brain. Thank you!